# How can I set auto increment id as 700 for my table even 1000 records existing on the same table?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database

I need to set the auto increment id (700) smaller than what last id of the table (Last Id : 1202). I am having almost 1202 records on my table. I just need to know is there any possibility to set the auto increment value smaller than last id?

If i set 700 as my auto increment id, what would happen for the existing 700th record on table?

Am using MySql database. Kindly give me an idea or suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would get constraint violation error if any row with id between 700 and 1202 exists in the table. What's the purpose of doing this?

Comment: @DarshanMehta  Actually I used the numbers (i.e:700 and 1202) for example. Really I have 60 thousands records in my table. For now the ids of the tables are getting hard to identify and getting bigger. So I just need a way to minimize the id digits.

Comment: There is no good reason why you'd want to do this

Comment: @Strawberry Yes May be. But I am not the owner to decide this. I am developer. I just want to make my client satisfied how much i can.

Comment: As your client, I would be extremely upset if you provided me with something that violated sensible RDBMS processes.

Comment: As the developer it's your job to tell the customer that their idea is bad. Sell this to them as a good thing and explain why. They will appreciate it in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot set the auto increment column value to a value that is already present in the table. As this is against the rule. Trying so will show `constraint violation error` and its also not a logical thing.